# Regex up to a special character and group of letters

Tags: regex, text, google-sheets, extract

Using Regex, I'm attempting to get back the following (stars denote what I'd like to extract) from each string using a single Regex command:

```
FO4H56FD-BTU (Follow Home 56): PLTD8

\***********

FO4H56FD-SYH-BI (Follow Home 56 SYH): PLTD8

\***********

FO4H52FD-SZH-AG4R-BI (Follow Home 52 SAH): QQTD8

\****************

FO4H58FD-SGH: (Follow Home 58 TGT): PLTS8

\***********
```

For some reason I'm having a lot of difficulties. I've been using various methods and currently have `=REGEXEXTRACT(A43,"(FO.+)\-BI")` which isn't working. Mine also isn't looking for the `:` currently. I was using a `|` for multiple rules which didn't seem to work out.

Comment: Could you please check and confirm if the final delimiter for a match can be a `:` or space?

Comment: Try `"^(.*?)(?:-BI)?(?:[ :]|$)"`

Comment: try `FO[A-Z0-9-]+(-BI)?`

Comment: Yes, either a space or a : would be the final delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A43,"^(.*?)(?:-BI)?(?:[ :]|$)")
```

[image]

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)`  - capturing group #1 matching any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `(?:-BI)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `-BI` substring
- `(?:[ :]|$)` - either a space, `:` or end of string

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. Hours of frustration solved in seconds!